# Riyaa - Ostentation

Tags: shirk

Allah loves when we help people. But if Muslims help their fellow brothers and sisters in worldly issues with the intention of impressing them, does this fall under the category of Riyaa?

Answer (score 1):

The action depends on the intention if whoever acts righteously for the sake of Allah then it is not Riyaa but if they have the intention to impress or show off then it is Riyaa.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].